# VSTS query - tasks in several iterations

Tags: azure-devops

I have a large team who is shuffling tasks around in different iterations. 
I need help to create a query in VSTS showing what PBI is having tasks in a different iteration than the PBI.

Ex.
PBI 1 - is in Sprint 1
 - Task 1 - is in Sprint 1
 - Task 2 - is in Sprint 2

Could anyone help me with such a query definition?

Answer (score 0):

- **To get tasks group by PBI**, you can use the type **Tree of work items** to create a query. Detail settings as below:

  [image]
- **To get tasks belong to a certain PBI** (such as p3 in below example), you can use below settings, so you can find all the tasks belong to the PBI which may locate in different interations:

  [image]